# HTML 5 Canvas Website

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a question in regards to using canvas to build your website.

Example: hellomonday.com

I am looking to create a more interactive website with canvas, and the above example is extremely well done.

It seems they are using fabric.js, but I don't see any canvas element. Is there a trick I am missing? Vague question surely but I wasn't sure how to get this information after trying to research this for a few hours.

Comment: _“but I don't see any canvas element”_ – where did you _look_? If you checked the initial HTML source code only, they might have been created dynamically via script later. Use `document.querySelectorAll('canvas')` in the browser console, that should help you find them.

Comment: They aren't using canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not using fabric.js, nor is it using the canvas element. All the transitions are being handled by GreenSock tweenMax (un-minify the main js file).

Comment: Thanks @korgrue, I will accept this as the right answer as it seems I completely misunderstood how that website was built. builtwith.com only detected fabric.js so that got me on the wrong lead!

Comment: I did not see any fabric.js script - but considering they jammed all the script on a single, thousands of lines long JS document - it is possible they use Fabric on some part of the build (I just did not see the library in the js doc), but the transitions between "pages" are definitely being animated using tweenMax and without the canvas.

Comment: Thanks a lot, been playing just now with tweenMax and understand now how they're animating all those elements like the page changeovers. Very clever stuff by them. :-)